# Estimating/approximating a very high dimensional unbounded poisson's equation

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, monte-carlo, potential-theory

Consider the poisson equation on an unbounded domain. Suppose that the solution is known to exist.
$$ \Delta u=f $$

I would like to estimate the solution of the this equation at a given point $x_0$. This is easily doable by numerical approximation, when in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$dimensional. However, I am interesting in $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d > 1000$ (at least). This clearly, render numerical approximation infeasible.

In the case, of a dirichlet poisson problem,

$$ \Delta u(x)= f(x), x \in \Omega $$
$$ u(x) = g(x), x \in \partial\Omega$$

One could use the Feynmann-Kac theorem, to express the solution $u$ as

$$ u(x) = \mathbb{E}_x[\int_{0}^{\tau_{\partial\Omega}} \frac{g(X_{\tau_{\partial\Omega}})}{\tau_{\partial\Omega}} - f(X_{t}) dt]$$
Where $X_{t}$ is a $d$ dimensional brownian motion with $X_0 = x$

In this case Monte-carlo estimation becomes straighforward.

1. Is there a similar approach to the unbounded poisson equation?
2. Is there any other estimate the solution of a very high dimensional poisson equation on an unbounded domain at given point?

Comment: In order to say "the solution", you need some sort of boundary condition, otherwise the solutions are highly nonunique (you can add any harmonic function).  Once you put in a suitable boundary condition, you might be able to approximate the solution in a bounded region by the solution to a problem on a somewhat larger bounded region with appropriate boundary conditions.